# one website two separate stores in magento

Tags: magento

I have a store in magento. I would like to keep only one website but add a possibility of having two stores. Each store will belong to a different owner so the invoices will be separate and the bank accounts where the money is transferred after payment will be different. The only thing that is common is the main website where people buy products. Is it possible to do? And if so how? thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "one website" and how do you want to differentiate the stores? Do you want you want something like http://shop1.example.com and http://shop2.example.com?

Comment: Hi Pierre-Jean. For the customer there will be no differentiation. So there will be just shop.example.com. That is the problem. It seems that everybodu wants so thave two webisites and one back end. I need one website and two back ends. I would appreciate any tips on how to do it. thanks.